# PHP Escaped special characters to html

Tags: php, html, htmlspecialchars

I have string that looks like this "v\u00e4lkommen till mig" that I get after doing utf8_encode() on the string.

I would like that string to become

```
 v&auml;lkommen till mig
```

where the character

```
  \u00e4 = ä = &auml;
```

How can I achive this in PHP?

Comment: you'll need to decode it and re-encode with `htmlentities`

Answer (score 3):

- Do not use utf8_(de|en)code. It just converts from UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 and back. ISO 8859-1 does not provide the same characters as ISO-8859-15 or Windows1252, which are the most used encodings (besides UTF-8). Better use mb_convert_encoding.
- *"v\u00e4lkommen till mig"* > This string looks like a JSON encoded string which IS already utf8 encoded. The unicode code positiotion of "ä" is U+00E4 >> *\u00e4*.

### Example

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$json = '"v\u00e4lkommen till mig"';
var_dump(json_decode($json)); //It will return a utf8 encoded string "välkommen till mig"
```

What is the source of this string?

There is no need to replace the *ä* with its HTML representation *&auml;*, if you print it in a utf8 encoded document and tell the browser the used encoding. If it is necessary, use `htmlentities`:

```
<?php
$json = '"v\u00e4lkommen till mig"';
$string = json_decode($json);
echo htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: as he pointed out in a comment on my answer, he wants to keep `<>` untouched, so your `htmlentities` option will need adjusting for that. Serving the document as UTF-8 should work fine.

Comment: I am not outputing text/html. The content-type is text/plain, the output is used in a Android app. And yes, i am using json_decode.

Comment: Hm.. When you are using json_decode, *\u00e4* should not appear in this string anymore. You can serve text/plain in utf8 equally: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` (But I do not get this, as your output is HTML obviously). Please give us some more code to make it easier for us to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you want to keep HTML characters, and I now think your source string isn't quite what you posted (I think it is actual unicode, rather than containing `\unnnn` as a string), I think your best option is this:

```
$html = str_replace( str_replace( str_replace( htmlentities( $whatever ), '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' ), '&amp;', '&' );
```

(note: no call to `utf8-decode`)

Original answer:

There is no direct conversion. First, decode it again:

```
$decoded = utf8_decode( $whatever );
```

then encode as HTML:

```
$html = htmlentities( $decoded );
```

and of course you can do it without a variable:

```
$html = htmlentities( utf8_decode( $whatever ) );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

To do this by regular expression (not recommended, likely slower, less reliable), you can use the fact that HTML supports `&#xnnnn;` constructs, where the `nnnn` is the same as your existing `\unnnn` values. So you can say:

```
$html = preg_replace( '/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', '&#x$1;', $whatever )
```

Comment: Hi, your first solution works. But the thing is that (sorry for not saying earlier) I have html tags in my string as well so a string can look like this "<p> v&auml;lkommen </p>", the solution makes the "<" into &lt;

Comment: In that case you either need to add special cases for `<>&` (do a final replace to convert them back) or use the regular expression. If this is user-submitted input, a more common option is to use a restricted markup and only convert it to HTML as a last step.

Comment: Thanks, tried your regex, but it does not seem to work. Have you tested it?

Comment: @mr.axelander I have, but I'm thinking there might be some confusion about your original format. You may have better luck with this one: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php#92777

Comment: or see my edit. I'm still not quite sure what your source string is, but I believe that line will work.

Answer (score 0):

The `html_entity_decode` worked for me.

```
$json = '"v\u00e4lkommen till mig"';
echo $decoded = html_entity_decode( json_decode($json) );
```